# django-hstore compatibility issue with Django 1.6

Tags: python, django, hstore, django-postgresql, django-hstore

[django-hstore](https://github.com/jordanm/django-hstore) seems to be not compatible with Django 1.6. I have this error on runserver. With Django 1.5.5 everything was correct. Any idea what could be the problem?

Note that I have changed the simplejson import by import json as mentionned in the warning but the problem persists.

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_orm\postgresql\hstore\forms.py:2: Deprecati
onWarning: django.utils.simplejson is deprecated; use json instead.
from django.utils import simplejson as json

Unhandled exception in thread started by
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 93, in w
rapper
fn(args, *kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
py", line 98, in inner_run
self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 310,
in validate
num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\validation.py", lin
e 34, in get_validation_errors
for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 196, in
get_app_errors
self.populate()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 78, in
_populate
self.loadapp(app_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 99, in
load_app
models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 40, in im
port_module
import(name)
File "c:\mygeosite\geodjango\basqui\models.py", line 13, in
from shapefile.models import *
File "c:\mygeosite\geodjango\shapefile\models.py", line 3, in
from django_orm.postgresql import hstore
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_orm\postgresql\hstore__init__.py",
line 2, in
from django_orm.postgresql.hstore.managers import HStoreManager
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_orm\postgresql\hstore\managers.py",
line 2, in
from django_orm.postgresql.hstore.query import HStoreQuerySet
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_orm\postgresql\hstore\query.py", li
ne 54, in
from django_orm.cache.query import CachedQuerySet
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_orm\cache\query.py", line 4, in dule>
from django.db.models.query import ITER_CHUNK_SIZE
ImportError: cannot import name ITER_CHUNK_SIZE
```

Comment: Why did you upgrade to Django 1.6? In general it's better to wait until the dependencies are compatible with 1.6

Comment: There is already an issue for this: https://github.com/jordanm/django-hstore/issues/11

Comment: you are right, but I wanted to take benefit from new features in geodjango that were introduced in 1.6. @jbub this is the issue I just opened a few hour ago

Comment: haha i tried to compare the nicknames, no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

happy to tell you the new version is compatible with django 1.6 and the development version supports python3 too.

Upgrade via pip and check the new official django-hstore github repository: https://github.com/djangonauts/django-hstore